# Saving lstm language model in Torch

Tags: lua, torch, lstm, cudnn

I am using the lstm language model in https://github.com/wojzaremba/lstm/blob/master/main.lua

I want to save the model at the end of training for later use. I added the following line at the end of training

```
torch.save(params.model_file, model)
```

Which seems to successfully save the model. However, when I try to load that model and test it, I get a very large perplexity. Just for testing, I ran a small training instance, which resulted in a test set perplexity of 134, then saved the model. I then loaded the saved model and applied exactly the same testing method (function run_test) on the same test set, but I got a huge perplexity of 71675.134 (even using random weights gives much lower perplexity than that!). I tried saving and loading only the weights, converting them to float() before saving, or saving them as cudaTensors, and all gave me the same result.

Here is the code for loading and testing after saving the whole model; I only modified the main method from the original main.lua:

```
local function main()
    g_init_gpu(arg)
    print('loading model from file ' .. params.model_file)
    model=torch.load(params.model_file)
    state_test =  {data=transfer_data(ptb.testdataset(params.batch_size))}
    reset_state(state_test)
    run_test()
end
```